# Mexican passport that has not been stamped by Mexico

Tags: usa, passports, domestic-travel, identity-cards

I have a friend that has her Mexican passport issued here in the USA but has not yet been stamped by Mexico. Can that be used as an ID to travel anywhere in the USA by airplane, or does she need an ID from USA?

Comment: Yes it can be used as an ID to travel by plane. What do you mean by `but has not yet being stamp by Mexico`? She doesn't need to visit Mexico for it to be stamped if it is a valid passport issued by Mexico.

Comment: Are you asking if you need a US Visa to travel to the United States?

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from the [TSA page on ID requirements](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/identification), a valid "foreign government-issued passport" is sufficient without any further requirement.

TSA officers only look at the ID page. They do not concern themselves with whether the passport has been used for international travel.